# How do I correctly call an HTTP API GET request to weatherstack?

Tags: reactjs, axios, weatherstack

I'm trying to do a GET request to api.weatherstack.com (see [documentation](https://weatherstack.com/documentation)).

Here's my react effect hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
      if (country === undefined) return
      console.log(country.name)
      axios
        .get('http://api.weatherstack.com/current', {
            params: {
              access_key: api_key, 
              query: country.name
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data)
          setWeather(response.data)
        })
    }, [api_key, country])
```

However, every single time I run this, I get this error:

{ code: 105, type: "https_access_restricted", info: "Access Restricted - Your current Subscription Plan does not support HTTPS Encryption." }

Doing the API call through my browser or through Postman works perfectly, so I'm thinking that there's probably an issue with how I'm using React or Axios.

Also, this API call works about 10% of the time, so I'm confused about why that might happen too.

Comment: Double check your real code...are you doing `https://` instead of `http://`?

Comment: What do you mean by real code? I'm confused

Comment: By "real", I mean the code you are actually are running as opposed to the code you postead here. We often see people post code that has typos that aren't in the code they are running. So I just wanted to double check if that is the case here.

Comment: I'm sure that this is the code I'm running. Just a bit confused about whether or not I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are using the free plan

[weatherstack.com https encryption](https://weatherstack.com/documentation)

Comment: I know I'm using the free plan, but shouldn't the HTTP endpoint be working? That's what I'm specifying in my code, at least

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.get("http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=YOUR_ACCESS_KEY&query=country.name)
```

on line 5.

Remove the `params: {}`  on lines 6-9

Answer (score 0):

Try:  [API Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enEqW.jpg)

url: http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=YOUR_ACCESS_KEYf&query=New%20York

From Documentation:
https://weatherstack.com/documentation